# Play store leaderboard not working unity

Tags: unity

I added a leaderboard on my android game using  cloudOnce and than i built an aab file and uploaded it on playstore to internal tester but leaderboard is not working.

Here is what happens when I click on leaderboard button using logCat [image]

Comment: This is extremely difficult to read, and as text in an image it won't be read by screen readers or indexed by search, limiting the audience who can find and access your question to help you with it. Please post this content as text instead of an image.

Comment: @DMGregory https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSUWE.png

Comment: That's still an image. Please edit your question to include this information as text, not an image file.